# How to disable TOUCH when remote using VNC?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

My solution has 2-machines where one is customer facing and the other is used by store personnel; in some situations when store personnel want to take control of the customer facing system we use UltraVNC to remote into it, push our application to a 2nd virtual display and put a PLEASE WAIT screen to the customer!

With Windows10 the concept of a virtual display is no longer possible so our remote view via UltraVNC lands on the primary display which means that the customer can SEE what the store personnel are doing and can also interact/interfere with it.... and this is my struggle today!

We found with UltraVNC we can "display user input" which works with keyboard/mouse but doesn't support blocking TOUCH input (we use a touchscreen) and there seems to be no way to put a PLEASE WAIT only to disable the screen (goes black - which has customers asking if the program crashed).

So opening this up to the general public to see if anyone has experience either with UltraVNC or has some completely different proposal for me to consider! I am open to all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You rely on windows solution, On linux there is a dbus messaging system , I don't know if there is a similar messaging system in windows.

You may have a powershell script that unplugs the display or the touchscreen input.
and send a toast message to user.

https://gist.github.com/atao/12b5857d388068bab134d5f9c36241b1